# Replacing a value in an XML document with another value taken from elsewhere in the document

Tags: shell-script, xml

Script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

tu=$(cat /export/home/a1016169/stack.txt;)
tu1=$(echo "$tu" | awk '/EM_CLIENT_VERSION/{x=NR+17}(NR<=x){print}' | awk '/tu/{x=NR+1}(NR<=x){getline; print}' | awk -F= '{print $(NR+2)}' | perl -lne 'print substr($_,19,5)';)
print "\n $tu1"

qc=$(cat /export/home/a1016169/stack.txt;)
qc1=$(echo "$qc" | awk '/EM_CLIENT_VERSION/{x=NR+17}(NR<=x){print}' | awk '/qc/{x=NR+1}(NR<=x){getline; print}' | awk -F= '{print $(NR+2)}' | perl -lne 'print substr($_,19,5)';)
print "\n $qc1"

sed 's/"$qc1"/"$tu1"/' - > /export/home/a1016169/stack.txt
```

`stack.txt` file:

```
 <prpr name = "EM_CLIENT_VERSION" encryptionClass = "com.hewitt.cat.tba.properties.encrypter.NoOpPropertyEncrypter">
                <lcycl name="pu">
                        <prprvl bgdt="2000.01.01 00:00" endt="3000.01.01 00:00">9999a</prprvl>
                </lcycl>
                <lcycl name="qc">
                        <prprvl bgdt="2000.01.01 00:00" endt="3000.01.01 00:00">9999a</prprvl>
                </lcycl>
                <lcycl name="qa">
                        <prprvl bgdt="2000.01.01 00:00" endt="3000.01.01 00:00">9999b</prprvl>
                </lcycl>
                <lcycl name="tu">
                        <prprvl bgdt="2000.01.01 00:00" endt="3000.01.01 00:00">0220a</prprvl>
                </lcycl>
                <lcycl name="dv">
                        <prprvl bgdt="2000.01.01 00:00" endt="3000.01.01 00:00"></prprvl>
                </lcycl>
            </prpr>
```

I'm getting an error from the last command as `Can't open -`.

I want to change `9999a` in `<lcycl name="qc">` (only under this section) to `0220a` value.  The value should be taken from `<lcycl name="tu">`.

Answer (score 4):

Using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -u '//lcycl[@name="qc"]/prprvl' -v 0220a file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<prpr name="EM_CLIENT_VERSION" encryptionClass="com.hewitt.cat.tba.properties.encrypter.NoOpPropertyEncrypter">
  <lcycl name="pu">
    <prprvl bgdt="2000.01.01 00:00" endt="3000.01.01 00:00">9999a</prprvl>
  </lcycl>
  <lcycl name="qc">
    <prprvl bgdt="2000.01.01 00:00" endt="3000.01.01 00:00">0220a</prprvl>
  </lcycl>
  <lcycl name="qa">
    <prprvl bgdt="2000.01.01 00:00" endt="3000.01.01 00:00">9999b</prprvl>
  </lcycl>
  <lcycl name="tu">
    <prprvl bgdt="2000.01.01 00:00" endt="3000.01.01 00:00">0220a</prprvl>
  </lcycl>
  <lcycl name="dv">
    <prprvl bgdt="2000.01.01 00:00" endt="3000.01.01 00:00"/>
  </lcycl>
</prpr>
```

The XPath `//lcycl[@name="qc"]/prprvl` would match the `prprvl` node that is the immediate child node of the `lcycl` node which has a `name` attribute with value `qc`.  Here, `xmlstarlet` will change the `prprvl` node's value to `0220a` regardless of what its initial value was.

If you don't want to hard code the `0220a` value, but pick it from the `//lcycl[@name="tu"]/prprvl` node, use

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//lcycl[@name="qc"]/prprvl' \
              -x '//lcycl[@name="tu"]/prprvl/text()' file.xml
```

Redirect the output to a new file and then rename the new file to the original name.

---

The equivalent thing in Perl, which will pick up `file.xml` from the current directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;

my $xp = XML::XPath->new( filename => 'file.xml' );

$xp->setNodeText( '//lcycl[@name="qc"]/prprvl', '0220a' );

my $nodeset = $xp->find('/');

foreach my $node ( $nodeset->get_nodelist() ) {
    print XML::XPath::XMLParser::as_string($node);
}
```

Here, if you want to pick that value from that other node, use

```
$xp->setNodeText( '//lcycl[@name="qc"]/prprvl',
    $xp->getNodeText('//lcycl[@name="tu"]/prprvl') );
```

instead of the other `setNodeText()` line.

Redirect the output to a new file and then rename the new file to the original name.

---

The error that you get is due to trying to open a file called `-`. GNU `sed` would treat `-` as the standard input stream, but other `sed` implementations (e.g. BSD `sed`) would see it as an ordinary filename.

In any case, you don't give `sed` any data to operate on.  This means that the file that you redirect to will be truncated and left empty.

Comment: not useful. I want the code to be written in unix and that code will pull the data from xml file and replace it

Comment: @user334028 I'm writing and testing this on a Unix system.  OpenBSD to be precise.

Comment: currently my script is able to store those data's in variable tu1 and qc1 but note able to replace it

Comment: what is BSD ???

Comment: @user334028 [A variant of Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution).  Listen, and this goes for your other XML parsing questions too... The only tool in your toolbox is a chainsaw. I'm asking you to go out and buy a fruit knife to peel this apple. A chainsaw will make a mess of it.

Comment: sorry but still not acceptable. as i know that it could be done using unix. So it's not a chainsaw but it's a knife. The only problem is that it's not sharp enough to cut the apple, but we can make it sharp

Comment: @user334028 A added another Unix solution, this time a Perl script.